# Controller specific functions in cakePHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have a piece of code in one of my controllers that I use to call the data for each action and subsequently each view. Rather than repeating the piece of code into each action, what is the best way to create a controller wide function in cakePHP? Or what is best practice?

Example controller:

```
function get_data($location) {
   $orders = $this->Post->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Post.field' => $location));
   return $orders;
}

//actual view
function index() {
   get_data(waiting);
   //etc. etc.
}

//actual view
function view_1() {
   get_data(view_1);
   //etc. etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be the fat model, skinny controller approach as outlined in this article.
http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/05/31/cakephp-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers/

You can declare a `public function custom_function ($data)` in the model and access them in the controller by `$this->Model->custom_function($data);`

Comment: retrieving data is for job for models! good article btw, +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

you can use some of this actions:

beforFilter: Called before the controller action

afterFilter: Called after the controller action is run and rendered.

beforeRender: Called after the controller action is run, but before the view is rendered.